# When should the server-side vs. client-side Facebook authentication flows be used?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook, oauth-2.0

Facebook has two flows for Authentication, client-side and server-side. When should each one be used?

Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Possibly related: [What is the purpose of the implicit grant authorization type in OAuth 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522831/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-implicit-grant-authorization-type-in-oauth-2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on your needs you can use one or the other or both.  If you want calls to facebook to be processed before the user sees a certain page then use server side... however if you want to display partial information until the user has authenticated, use javascript authentication.

It boils down to this:

- **Javascript authentication** can happen with-in a popup window and does not require a page reload you can also just perform a top.location.href redirect.
- **PHP authentication** involves a redirect to an authentication page.

---

Also see [this thread](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg07889.html), in particular [this response](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg07896.html).

Comment: if the access_token is generated from a server-side OAuth call, the resulting access_token will have the longer expiration time by default http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067947/facebook-access-token-server-side-vs-client-side-flows

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Lix's answer, I would say:

**Client Side Authentication**

- When you want some information from Facebook API about the user that is required once, as in you only need to get it once like the user's name and email.
- When you want to temporarily access/manage the user's information/data and don't need to do it often.
- You get a temporary token, which is valid only for a few hours and you need to get a new token to call the Facebook API again after it has expired (which requires the user has to grant permission again).

**Server Side Authentication**

- You want to manage the user's data (on their behalf) after the user has left your website/app. Example, gathering the user's feed/timeline data on a regular basis.
- When you want to access/manage the user's information/data in a recurring fashion untill the user hasn't revoked access to your client id (represented by a Facebook app).
- You get both a temporary token and a permanent token (which lasts for about 60 days at the time of writing this). You can get a new temporary token by using the permanent token every time you need to call the Facebook API (given the previous temporary token has expired) -- without bothering the user to grant permission again.

So, in short, for short term use, follow client-side authentication flow and for long term use follow server-side authentication (given you have a backend server of your own).