# django rest-auth Facebook registration

Tags: django, django-rest-auth

I am trying to register users via Facebook using django rest-auth.

As per the installation docs [here](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_endpoints.html), a rest call to register a user via facebook requires an "access token" and "code". I know what an access token is, but what is "code"?

Comment: Go to https://developers.facebook.com/ in order to find out.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Well I did look around for sometime and I could not figure out. What's wrong in asking if I cannot find the solution?

Comment: @user3282666 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666316/facebook-oauth-2-0-code-and-token

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to create a Facebook Application in the [developers](http://developers.facebook.com) page. You will get a Facebook app code and a secret.

For using the /rest-auth/facebook/ method from the django-rest-auth, you need to send the access code (obtained using the javascript SDK) and the code of the Facebook Application.

Finally, before using this method, you have to go the the application back-office and create a social application, using the Facebook app code and the secret.