# How to properly use an access token within a long running background process?

Tags: security, keycloak, openid-connect

we are looking for some advice on how to use an access token within a long running background process that exceeds the token expiry. We are using Keycloak with OpenId Connect and we would like to stick to the standard. Maybe bend it a little bit, if necessary, but not overthrow it.

Use-Case:
User calls a service with his access token. The service starts a long running background process that calls other services. The access token is being sent to the other services in order to authorize the request and relate the action to the user (e.g. "changed by"). The background process may take days or even weeks.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need refresh token with offline_access scope. Such refresh token never expires and is used to get new access token when the old one expires.

To get refresh token with offline_access from KeyCloak user needs to have offline_access role and you should add "offline_access" to requested scopes.

More on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638344/1540748

Another option is Client Credentials flow, but than you don't have user data in token.

Comment: We have given this a try but there are some downsides to this approach:
1) the client that uses the offline token needs to be the same as the one who did the login
2) we don't want updated roles or attributes
3) the offline token has an expiry, too
4) how to identify which offline token belongs to which background process?
5) we observed performance issues within keycloak when it has to deal with many many offline token (= many background process instances)

Comment: 1) The client or the user? Both are the same.

Comment: 3) Offline token does not have expiry. If you configure everything right expiry is 0 in your token. Does your user have offline_access role? Did you send offline_access in scope in the token request?

Comment: 1) I was talking about the client_id that needs to be passed with the request. If client B tries to refresh a token that has been given to client A, it will receive an "invalid_grant" error.

Comment: 3) I am sorry, I was wrong. The exiry of the offline token is indeed 0.

Comment: 1) Yes, that is normal behaviour. Client_id has to be the same when you ask for new access token with refresh token as the client_id from first request.

Comment: Another option is to use client credentials flow. It is used for service to service request, but in that case you don't have specific user data in tokens.

Comment: 2) I don't think it is possible to get roles and attributes from previous timepoint. 4) It is your business logic. You need to persist session. 5) I didn't have performance issues, but first thing I would check is database. Which one do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213767/discussion-between-stphngrtz-and-andrija).