# How do I get tokens for a Google Web application using oauth.tools?

Tags: oauth, google-iam, oauth.tools

I would like to use [OAuth.tools](https://oauth.tools) to get an access token, refresh token, and ID token for my Web application that I've setup in Google Identity Platform? I'm unsure how to configure OAuth.tools to communicate with Google's OAuth server, and there are various flows, but I'm not sure which applies to my Web application. What should I fill in here, for instance, to make it work with OAuth.tools:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to:

1. Configure the client at Google (the screenshot above)
2. Setup an environment in OAuth.tools to be able communicate with Google's identity platform
3. Perform the code flow

First, the `origins` of the Web application should should be set to `https://oauth.tools`. The `redirect URIs` should be set to `https://oauth.tools/callback/code`.

[image]

After you create the client, take note of its client ID and secret. You'll need them later to configure OAuth.tools.

Next, in OAuth.tools, create a new environment:

[image: open environment modal]

[image: new environment]

In the `Issuer` field, enter `https://accounts.google.com/` and click `Refresh`. This will populate all of the endpoints from the [Google discovery document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#discovery). You can give the environment a nice name too if you want:

[image]

Next, on the `Client` tab, click `+ New client`. Then, enter the `Client ID` of the Google client you took note of. Set the secret as well and toggle on `Code Flow`:

[image]

Close that modal, and then create a new flow:

[image]

Select `Code Flow`:

[image]

In the environment dropdown, make sure the one you created is selected:

[image]

In the `Client ID` text combobox, pick the one you created in the environment. Select `openid` or type it and hit enter. Click the `Run` button:

[image]

Login at Google and consent to the app if you're prompted to.

Finally, after you get back to OAuth.tools, hit `Redeem Code` next to step 3:

[image]

In the result pane on the right, you'll see the access token and ID token.

[image]

If you want a refresh token as well, checkout this answer that explains more about [how to obtain a refresh token from Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637984/what-does-offline-access-in-oauth-mean).