# How do I add my own OAuth server to OAuth.tools?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, oauth.tools

I am trying to add my server to [OAuth.tools](https://oauth.tools). I clicked the `Environment` button as described in the [getting started video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvhUTHiofe0&feature=youtu.be). I see a long list of input fields:

[image]

Do I have to fill all these in myself?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways of adding an OAuth Authorization Server (AS) or OpenID Connect Provider (OP) in [OAuth.tools](https://oauth.tools):

1. Manually filling in the various endpoints
2. By providing an OpenID Connect issuer
3. By providing OpenID Connect or OAuth metadata
4. Using WebFinger and OpenID provider issuer discovery

The first option might seem like a lot of work, but it can be the only option at times. For a server that doesn't support metadata, this is the only choice. Such servers usually don't support all the endpoints listed on that page, so you typically would only need to fill in a couple.

The second option is helpful to quickly add an OP. Just typing in the issuer into the `Issuer` textfield and click `Discover`. This will append `/.well-known/openid-configuration` to the issuer URL and fetch metadata from there. If all goes well, the endpoint textfields will be populated automatically!

If the server doesn't support OpenID Connect metadata but [OAuth metadata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8414), the above option *may* not work in some cases because the URL might not end with `/.well-known/openid-configuration`. You may also have the entire metadata URL in your clipboard and don't want to delete the end part. In such cases, just enter the metadata URL in the textfield with that label and hit `Discover`. Again, if all goes well, the endpoints will be automatically populated. (If both the `Issuer` and `Metadata URL` fields are filled in when `Discover` is clicked, the later will be used.)

The final way is using [WebFinger](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7033) and [OpenID provider issuer discovery](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#IssuerDiscovery). To use this, hit the `Use WebFinger` button in your screenshot there. Then, enter a resource. This could be an email address, host name, or other. If the server supports this and all goes as expected, the WebFinger modal will be closed and all endpoints will be filled in.

For an example of how to set this up using Google's identity service, [checkout this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63657208/150435).