# Mixing authorization code and implicit grant type in OAuth2

Tags: javascript, ajax, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I have some questions for the following flow involving OAuth2:

webapp1.xyz.com is a registered client with authorization code grant type, here's the current flow:

1. User logged in and redirected with authorization code to webapp1.xyz.com
2. webapp1.xyz.com exchange authorization code for access token and store it to session
3. webapp1.xyz.com server side needs to make calls to webapp2.xyz.com api by passing on access token
4. webapp1.xyz.com has SPA where ajax calls webapp1.xyz.com api end point (passing on session cookies in request)
5. User logged out, session is destroyed

There is a suggestion from someone to make the ajax call using (implicit grant) access token instead of session cookies. Is that even possible mixing authorization code and implicit grant type? Maybe I am mixing something, I cannot see any reason why using implicit grant type for the ajax part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522831/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-implicit-grant-authorization-type-in-oauth-2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa. I think this link answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that even possible mixing authorization code and implicit grant
>   type?

The problem is more that you talking about one token for two applications. Or rather, webapp1 is both an OAuth client (web site which calls a web API - webapi2) and an OAuth resource (a web API which the SPA can call using implicit grant).

So: SPA javascript > webapp1.xyz.com application > webapp2.xyz.com application.

In Oauth2.0 terms your SPA client app would be a client, and webapp1 and webapp2 would be resources. the client would ideally use the implicit grant to get an access token as that's the optimised flow for a public, javascript client.

If possible, maybe look at a hybrid flow - OAuth2 and OpenID Connect - instead of the authorisation code flow.

Using the hybrid flow, webapp1 will get a token as currently, but it will also get an ID token which it can pass back to the SPA.

The ID token is intended for use by a client for authentication purposes - this ID token could do the same job the session cookie was doing (i.e. authentication between SPA and SPA backend). And the access token would be stored safely on the webapp1 server away from the SPA.

Comment: This is a scenario where "webapp1 is both an OAuth client (web site which calls a web API - webapi2) and an OAuth resource (a web API which the SPA can call using implicit grant)". I was not aware an ID token received thru authorization flow can be passed to SPA, i was under the impression, ID token is not to be exposed to user-agent.  If ID token is passed to SPA and SPA can use the token and make request to webapp1, all webapp1 needs to do is to verify the token?  thanks!

Comment: Exactly. You can have SPAs which use server side to pass tokens back to the user agent. Microsoft Azure portal is an example. If there's no delegated access between spa and webapp1  needed, then the id token would work to aid authentication.

Comment: Passing id token received during authorization code flow to SPA, is this a right practice? thanks!

Comment: At the point your redirect URL gets the Auth code it will get an id_token. No reason why it can't supply that when it returns the spa resources as far as I can see. Either that or register a client for the spa as well and handle two token requests. Spa implicit grant and webapp1 Auth code grant.